# Doing a POST request on Flutter using the http package

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-http

I am trying to hit this endpoint on using flutter. https://docs.particle.io/reference/device-cloud/api/#generate-an-access-token

I've got it working on POSTMAN and curl

```
curl version: 
    curl https://api.particle.io/oauth/token \
       -u particle:particle \
       -d grant_type=password \
       -d "my.email@gmail.com" \
       -d "my_password"
```

Postman: 
[image: Authorisation]
[image: Body]

On both curl and postman, I get a response back with the access token.

But when I try to implement this on Flutter I am getting an error response. 
Here my code on Flutter.

```
Future<Response> getPublicKey() async {
LoginRequestModel requestModelBody = LoginRequestModel(grantType: "password",
    username: "my.email@gmail.com", password: "my_password");
Map<String, dynamic> requestBody = requestModelBody.toJson();
String bodyString = json.encode(requestBody);
//    String formBody = Uri.encodeQueryComponent(bodyString);
print("Body string: "+bodyString);
String url = "https://api.particle.io/oauth/token";
String credentials = "particle:particle";

Map<String, String> headers = {
  HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
  HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: "Authorization $credentials",
};

return await post(url, headers: headers, body: bodyString);
```

}

The print statement printing out the body string prints out:

```
{"grant_type":"password","username":"my.email@gmail.com","password":"my.email@gmail.com"}
```

This is the error I get back:

```
{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Invalid or missing grant_type parameter"}
```

I am guessing I am doing the form encoding wrong, but I can't figure out the right way to form encod the body.

Question: How do I hit the REST endpoint documented [here](https://docs.particle.io/reference/device-cloud/api/#generate-an-access-token) using flutter?

Answer (score 1):

There's a great [website](https://curl.trillworks.com/#dart) to convert `curl` commands to Dart code.

Pasting your curl command gives:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() async {
  var uname = 'particle';
  var pword = 'particle';
  var authn = 'Basic ' + base64Encode(utf8.encode('$uname:$pword'));

  var data = {
    'grant_type': 'password',
    'my.email@gmail.com': '',
    'my_password': '',
  };

  var res = await http.post('https://api.particle.io/oauth/token', headers: {'Authorization': authn}, body: data);
  if (res.statusCode != 200) throw Exception('post error: statusCode= ${res.statusCode}');
  print(res.body);
}
```

Comparing with your Postman screenshot seems to indicate that your curl command isn't actually correct, so I'd change it to:

```
  var data = {
    'grant_type': 'password',
    'username': 'my.email@gmail.com',
    'password': 'my_password',
  };
```